# Creating a JSON object from a tabbed tree text file

Tags: python

I have this examle of a text file: (I dont know what you call this, a Tree?)

```
key1
    subkey1
    subkey2
        choice1
key2
    subkey1
    subkey2
```

I want it to look like this:

```
[
    {   
        "text":"key1",
        "children":[
            {   
                "text":"subkey1",
                children:[]
            },
            {
                "text":"subkey2",
                children:[
                    {
                        "text":"choice1",
                        "children":[]
                    }
                ]
            },
        ]
    },
    {   
        "text":"key2",
        "children":[
            {   
                "text":"subkey1",
                children:[]
            },
            {   
                "text":"subkey2",
                children:[]
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

This is what Im doing, I do not understand how you get the children elements into the parent, and this should be able to go infinitely deep.

```
import itertools
def r(f, depth, parent, l, children):
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip()
        newDepth = sum(1 for i in itertools.takewhile(lambda c: c=='\t', line))
        node = line.strip()
        if parent is not None:
            print parent, children
            children = [{"txt":node, "children":[]}]
            # l.append({"txt":parent, "children":children})
        r(f, newDepth, node, l, children)
json_list = []
r(open("test.txt"), 0, None, json_list, [])
print json_list
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First rule, avoid recursion if you can... Here you only need to know the ancestors, and they can be easily maintained in a list. Note that `depth` 0 is reserved for the root node, and the first "user" depth is `1`, hence the `+1` when counting the tabs.

```
f = open("/tmp/test.txt", "r")

depth = 0
root = { "txt": "root", "children": [] }
parents = []
node = root
for line in f:
    line = line.rstrip()
    newDepth = len(line) - len(line.lstrip("\t")) + 1
    print newDepth, line
    # if the new depth is shallower than previous, we need to remove items from the list
    if newDepth < depth:
        parents = parents[:newDepth]
    # if the new depth is deeper, we need to add our previous node
    elif newDepth == depth + 1:
        parents.append(node)
    # levels skipped, not possible
    elif newDepth > depth + 1:
        raise Exception("Invalid file")
    depth = newDepth

    # create the new node
    node = {"txt": line.strip(), "children":[]}
    # add the new node into its parent's children
    parents[-1]["children"].append(node)

json_list = root["children"]
print json_list
```

Comment: Why is it recommended to avoid recursion?

Comment: @tom Funny enough, one of the answers is "stack overflow"... Recursion is often computationally expensive and uses a lot of memory (stack). I am not claiming recursion would always be bad, people have been killed for less. Technically speaking, heap is usually safer and less limited memory to use, and list operations may be faster than expensive function calls. This, however, depends on the environment (language, machine, etc.) My religion does not forbid recursion, but it needs to be used with good understanding and only when really needed.